# Parameter expansion with cron

Tags: bash, variables, cron, sh, parameter-expansion

My script.sh contains parameter expansion something like this

```
variable=${variable/PUT_CONTENT/$data}
```

This should replace the substring PUT_CONTENT with variable data. If I run the script manually in terminal like this: `./script.sh` everything works (also the replacing). But the command with replacing doesn't work when I put the script.sh into the crontab file. I need run the script every 5 minutes. - None of variable expansion doesnt work in script which is started by cron.

```
*/5 * * * * sh -c "/root/script.sh"
```

Comment: have you verified the variables (`$variable` and `$date`) are being populated when the script is run via `cron`? how are these variables populated in the script?

Comment: That should work but are you sure that the variables `variable` (not a good name)  and `data` are defined in the context of the user owner of the cron job ?

Comment: I got it, the problem was that i didnt have the first line with `#!/bin/bash`